# Create a oauth-token for integration tests

Tags: testing, oauth-2.0, keycloak

We want to create a "long lasting" token for integration testing purposes. We are using a keycloak for creating tokens normally. But I don't see a possibility to create tokens with no expiration, so that reoccuring integration tests on dev-stage can be done without interuption.

What would you suggest for such automatically repeating testing regarding oauth?

Comment: From Realm configuration - Access token lifespan, the value can be configured. By default, it is set to 1 minute. Have you checked this option to create an access token with longer lifetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All access token should expire at some point, that why the rfc details the use of refresh token, wich can be used indefinitly to keep your service running, the basic idea is that when you request an access token, you'll get an access token plus a refresh token, and when the first token expires, you send it to the keycloak server and it will regenerate a new access token and a new refresh token.

In practice, you should use your token as long as its valid (since you know in advance it lifespan), and when your token is about to expire you resend the request using the refresh token.

src: [RFC oauth2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749)

Answer (score 1):

How about make longer time(a couple of days) for access token before start integration test?

After finish integration test, return to default time(5 minutes).

This is my demo test steps

1. Get master of realm access token and assign token variable
   [image]
   [image]
2. Get my-realm's realm data
   [image]
   this is default my-realm's setting data

```
{
    "id": "my-realm",
    "realm": "my-realm",
    "notBefore": 0,
    "defaultSignatureAlgorithm": "RS256",
    "revokeRefreshToken": false,
    "refreshTokenMaxReuse": 0,
    "accessTokenLifespan": 300,
    "accessTokenLifespanForImplicitFlow": 900,
    "ssoSessionIdleTimeout": 1800,
    "ssoSessionMaxLifespan": 36000,
    "ssoSessionIdleTimeoutRememberMe": 0,
    "ssoSessionMaxLifespanRememberMe": 0,
    "offlineSessionIdleTimeout": 2592000,
    "offlineSessionMaxLifespanEnabled": false,
    "offlineSessionMaxLifespan": 5184000,
    "clientSessionIdleTimeout": 0,
    "clientSessionMaxLifespan": 0,
    "clientOfflineSessionIdleTimeout": 0,
    "clientOfflineSessionMaxLifespan": 0,
    "accessCodeLifespan": 60,
    "accessCodeLifespanUserAction": 300,
    "accessCodeLifespanLogin": 1800,
    "actionTokenGeneratedByAdminLifespan": 43200,
    "actionTokenGeneratedByUserLifespan": 300,
    "oauth2DeviceCodeLifespan": 600,
    "oauth2DevicePollingInterval": 5,
    "enabled": true,
    "sslRequired": "external",
    "registrationAllowed": false,
    "registrationEmailAsUsername": false,
    "rememberMe": false,
    "verifyEmail": false,
    "loginWithEmailAllowed": true,
    "duplicateEmailsAllowed": false,
    "resetPasswordAllowed": false,
    "editUsernameAllowed": false,
    "bruteForceProtected": false,
    "permanentLockout": false,
    "maxFailureWaitSeconds": 900,
    "minimumQuickLoginWaitSeconds": 60,
    "waitIncrementSeconds": 60,
    "quickLoginCheckMilliSeconds": 1000,
    "maxDeltaTimeSeconds": 43200,
    "failureFactor": 30,
    "defaultRole": {
        "id": "3798f9f6-3383-474e-997e-123d9b534ae4",
        "name": "default-roles-my-realm",
        "description": "${role_default-roles}",
        "composite": true,
        "clientRole": false,
        "containerId": "my-realm"
    },
    "requiredCredentials": [
        "password"
    ],
    "otpPolicyType": "totp",
    "otpPolicyAlgorithm": "HmacSHA1",
    "otpPolicyInitialCounter": 0,
    "otpPolicyDigits": 6,
    "otpPolicyLookAheadWindow": 1,
    "otpPolicyPeriod": 30,
    "otpSupportedApplications": [
        "FreeOTP",
        "Google Authenticator"
    ],
    "webAuthnPolicyRpEntityName": "keycloak",
    "webAuthnPolicySignatureAlgorithms": [
        "ES256"
    ],
    "webAuthnPolicyRpId": "",
    "webAuthnPolicyAttestationConveyancePreference": "not specified",
    "webAuthnPolicyAuthenticatorAttachment": "not specified",
    "webAuthnPolicyRequireResidentKey": "not specified",
    "webAuthnPolicyUserVerificationRequirement": "not specified",
    "webAuthnPolicyCreateTimeout": 0,
    "webAuthnPolicyAvoidSameAuthenticatorRegister": false,
    "webAuthnPolicyAcceptableAaguids": [],
    "webAuthnPolicyPasswordlessRpEntityName": "keycloak",
    "webAuthnPolicyPasswordlessSignatureAlgorithms": [
        "ES256"
    ],
    "webAuthnPolicyPasswordlessRpId": "",
    "webAuthnPolicyPasswordlessAttestationConveyancePreference": "not specified",
    "webAuthnPolicyPasswordlessAuthenticatorAttachment": "not specified",
    "webAuthnPolicyPasswordlessRequireResidentKey": "not specified",
    "webAuthnPolicyPasswordlessUserVerificationRequirement": "not specified",
    "webAuthnPolicyPasswordlessCreateTimeout": 0,
    "webAuthnPolicyPasswordlessAvoidSameAuthenticatorRegister": false,
    "webAuthnPolicyPasswordlessAcceptableAaguids": [],
    "browserSecurityHeaders": {
        "contentSecurityPolicyReportOnly": "",
        "xContentTypeOptions": "nosniff",
        "xRobotsTag": "none",
        "xFrameOptions": "SAMEORIGIN",
        "contentSecurityPolicy": "frame-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; object-src 'none';",
        "xXSSProtection": "1; mode=block",
        "strictTransportSecurity": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
    },
    "smtpServer": {},
    "eventsEnabled": false,
    "eventsListeners": [
        "jboss-logging"
    ],
    "enabledEventTypes": [],
    "adminEventsEnabled": false,
    "adminEventsDetailsEnabled": false,
    "identityProviders": [],
    "identityProviderMappers": [],
    "internationalizationEnabled": false,
    "supportedLocales": [],
    "browserFlow": "browser",
    "registrationFlow": "registration",
    "directGrantFlow": "direct grant",
    "resetCredentialsFlow": "reset credentials",
    "clientAuthenticationFlow": "clients",
    "dockerAuthenticationFlow": "docker auth",
    "attributes": {
        "cibaBackchannelTokenDeliveryMode": "poll",
        "cibaExpiresIn": "120",
        "cibaAuthRequestedUserHint": "login_hint",
        "oauth2DeviceCodeLifespan": "600",
        "oauth2DevicePollingInterval": "5",
        "parRequestUriLifespan": "60",
        "cibaInterval": "5"
    },
    "userManagedAccessAllowed": false,
    "clientProfiles": {
        "profiles": []
    },
    "clientPolicies": {
        "policies": []
    }
}
```

3. Extend logger period of access(2 days) token lifetime
   I changed **accessTokenLifespan** value from 300 to 172800 (= 3600 * 24 *2) seconds
   use **PUT** method for update realm data
   [image]
   In the UI of Keycloak, the **Access Token Lifespan** will be changed into 2 days
   [image]
   the Status of API call should be return 204 (No Content)
4. Run your integration tests
5. Return back 2.'s default(or previous) lifetime
   [image]