# Add predefined list of attributes for role in keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I need to inspect a possibility to create role in a keycloak admin GUI with predefined attributes. Can this attributes been saved and appear in every new role?
I've searched many resources and repos but could not find the answer.

I use keycloak 18.0.2 working on quarkus.

Answer (score 0):

You can add(or update) list of attributes for role

1. Get the master realm token
   see the [Create a oauth-token for integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72879216/create-a-oauth-token-for-integration-tests/72891991#72891991)
2. Get the my-realm roles list - copy the name you want to add attributes

[image]

3. Update attribute

[image]

4. Check it attributes added
   [image]